# ¿Cómo centrar varios div verticalmente?

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo puedo centrar varios div verticalmente? Este es mi código para centrar horizontalmente:

```css
    #nav{
        width:100%;
        height:64px;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .separacion_1{
        width:90%;
        height:4px;
        border-radius:10px;
        background-color:#ccc;
        margin:0 auto;
        margin-bottom:3px;
        margin-top:4px;
    }
    .btn{
        width:47px;
        height:47px;
        margin:3px;
        display:inline-table;
    }
    .btn_enviar{
        width:57px;
        height:47px;
        margin:3px;
        display:inline-table;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="nav">
                <div class="separacion_1"></div>
                <div id="0" class="btn">H</div>
                <div id="0" class="btn">C</div>
                <div id="0" class="btn btn_enviar ">E</div>
                <div id="0" class="btn">F</div>
                <div id="0" class="btn">A</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: mi problema es que ahora quiero hacer el nav vertical y que H C E F A esten debajo uno de otros y centrados en el div nav

Comment: Ahora el nav esta horizontal pero a partir de pantallas 600px el nav sera vertical con un ancho de 64px y lo que no puedo hacer es centrar las cosas vertical dentro del nav

Comment: Intente dar al nav display:table y a btn display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle; asi lo centra pero ya los pone una a lado del otro y le quita el ancho del btn

Comment: ¿Porqué no usas [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

Comment: Porque solo las versiones nuevas de navegador soporta eso

Answer (score 0):

Te hago los siguientes comentarios:

- No creo que para el resultado que expones debas usar: `position:absolute;` así como tampoco: `display:inline-table;`
- Con un poco de CSS Grid y unos detalles mas lo podemos lograr de manera mas simple
- Indicamos dentro de una media query que cuando los pixeles sean mínimo x cantidad entonces reajustamos por medio de `grid-template-columns` para lograr que los dic aparezcan uno debajo del otro
- En conjunto con lo anterior podemos centrar vertical y horizontalmente por medio de `place-content`

Código de ejemplo:

```html
    <style>
      *  {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      
      #nav {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
        height: 100vh;
        justify-items: center;
        align-items: end;
      }
    
      @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        #nav {
          place-content: center;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <div id="nav">
                <div id="0" class="btn">H</div>
                <div id="0" class="btn">C</div>
                <div id="0" class="btn btn_enviar ">E</div>
                <div id="0" class="btn">F</div>
                <div id="0" class="btn">A</div>
    </div>
```

Comentarios finales:

- No es que la forma que lo haces sea incorrecta pero me parece *demasiado trabajo* cuando se puede lograr con menos líneas
- Te dejo el resto de la inclusión de los detalles estéticos a ti

**Enlaces útiles**

- [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)
- [alineación de elementos en el eje de bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout#alineaci%C3%B3n_de_elementos_en_el_eje_de_bloque)
- [place-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content)

Comment: ya pero el grid no es compatible con todos los navegadores

Comment: @Daniel que navegadores se supone usarás?

Comment: chrome, mozilla  de los moviles

Comment: Pues he de decirte @DanielOvidiu que para esos navegadores [móviles CSS Grid](https://caniuse.com/css-grid) va bastante bien